# Could not connect to SMTP host PHP Mailer

Tags: php, email, ssl

I'm using phpmailer to send email. This is my code.

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'mail.distech.com.my';                    
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'myemail';                  
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          
$mail->Port = 587;
```

I've used this code on my computer and it works. The email is been send. However, when I run this code on my friends computer, an error appears.

**The error :**

```
2015-06-19 08:42:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 192.168.1.20 
2015-06-19 08:42:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS  Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto() [function.stream-socket-enable-crypto]: SSL: The operation completed successfully. in C:\xampp\htdocs\ehars\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 344 
2015-06-19 08:42:12 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
2015-06-19 08:42:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT  Notice: fwrite() [function.fwrite]: send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in C:\xampp\htdocs\ehars\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 937 
2015-06-19 08:42:12 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
2015-06-19 08:42:12 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

What could be the problem as I am new to phpmailer. I have tried pinging mail.distech.com.my on both computer and both works perfectly fine. Please help me thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPMailer - SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997068/phpmailer-smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with upgrading PHP version.

As well enable below line in php.ini file and restart apche server.

```
; extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: I have enable the above line in php.ini. It is still the same. Could it be that older xampp version could cause this problem?

Comment: it may be, you can upgrade PHP version.

Comment: Adding extension to php.ini solved for me (php 5.3.4)