# PHPMailer - SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send email using PHPMailer. When I tried sending the email from gmail account, it works perfectly fine. However, I would like to send the email from my own SMTP, but there seems to be an error. What could be the problem? Please help me. Thank you.

**Using smtp.gmail.com :**

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';                 
$mail->Password = 'password';                               
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
$mail->Port = 587;
```

**Using mail.distech.com.my :**

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'mail.distech.com.my';                    
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'myemail@distech.com.my';                 
$mail->Password = 'password';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587; 

$mail->From = 'myemail@distech.com.my';
$mail->addAddress('amalina@distech.com.my');     
$mail->Subject = 'Test';
$mail->Body    = 'Test message';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

**Error using mail.distech.com.my**

```
2015-06-23 06:58:45 Connection: opening to mail.distech.com.my:587, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 
2015-06-23 06:58:45 Connection: opened 
2015-06-23 06:58:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-server.firstonline-server16.com ESMTP Exim 4.85 #2 Tue, 23 Jun 2015 14:58:45 +0800 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 
2015-06-23 06:58:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 192.168.1.20 
2015-06-23 06:58:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.firstonline-server16.com Hello 192.168.1.20 [115.135.120.220] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP 
2015-06-23 06:58:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2015-06-23 06:58:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead 
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto() [function.stream-socket-enable-crypto]: SSL: The operation completed successfully. in C:\xampp\htdocs\ehars\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 344
2015-06-23 06:58:46 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
2015-06-23 06:58:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
Notice: fwrite() [function.fwrite]: send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in C:\xampp\htdocs\ehars\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 937
2015-06-23 06:58:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2015-06-23 06:58:46 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
2015-06-23 06:58:46 Connection: closed 2015-06-23 06:58:46  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

**UPDATE :**

Checked my phpinfo () and the ssl has been enabled.

[image]

Comment: check port number of your smtp host

Comment: Did you try following the link to the docs in the error log and doing what it says?

Comment: @UzumakiIchigo the port number for my stmp host is 587

Comment: @Synchro yes i did. I have tried pinging my smtp host and it works fine. I even tried sending email from the same smtp host from a different computer, and again it works fine. But when I tried sending from a different computer, this problem occur.

Comment: The error says "We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail" -- contact your webhost, or google it if it is your own server.

Comment: @UzumakiIchigo that's just a greeting message, not an error.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your PHP and openssl extension because the call to `stream_socket_enable_crypto` is failing (despite the unhelpful 'completed successfully' message!). Make sure you're using at least PHP 5.6 and that openssl is enabled.

Comment: try enabling extension=php_openssl.dll if not enabled. (https://code.google.com/p/jaxl/issues/detail?id=3) It may be because the extension is disabled, or ssl version mismatch b/w client and server or something else. Synchro ninja'd me

Comment: Similar problem is solved by using port 25 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723404/mediatemple-cant-send-email-using-codeigniter)

Comment: @Synchro hi sir, I'm just wondering cause I've checked my PHP version is 5.3.8. So could it be that the older version of PHP is the reason why I cannot send my email. Thanks!

Comment: @Synchro and also I've checked my phpinfo and it looks like my openssl has been enabled.